# Python Selenium How to take grandchild text

Tags: python, selenium

I am working with this website= https://www.offerte.smartpaws.de/

In the final page once you have put all your variables in, we get a page with this info:

[image]

and  the HTML for the price looks like this:

[image]

I am looking to store the prices for each product, but it seems like I have to select the parent element based on the text "Optimal Care", "Classic Case", etc.. and go down to the child element to extract the price.
I am not sure how to do this, my current code for this specific scenario:

`price_optimal = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@class="summary-table-title" and @text="Optimal Care"]/*/*/'))).get_attribute("text()")`

How would I take a text based on a parent element text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only retrieve price then you can use the below XPath:

```
//div[@class='summary-table-price price-monthly']//div[2]
```

with `find_elements` or with `explicit waits`.

1. With `find_elements`

**Code:**

```
for price in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='summary-table-price price-monthly']//div[2]"):
    print(price.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

2. With `ExplicitWaits:`

   ```
   for price in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='summary-table-price price-monthly']//div[2]"))):
       print(price.get_attribute('innerText'))
   ```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If you want to extract based on the plan name such as `Classic Care`

You should use the below XPath:

```
//div[text()='Classic Care']//following-sibling::div[@class='summary-table-price price-monthly']/descendant::div[2]
```

and use it like this:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Classic Care']//following-sibling::div[@class='summary-table-price price-monthly']/descendant::div[2]"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
```

Also, for other plans, all you will have to do is to replace `Classic care` with `Optimal Care` or `Basic care` in the XPath.

Comment: How would you get the value for an "uncle" elemenent? So I land at the child of an element, and the text I want is the sibling of the parent element. Looking at the "Jährliches Limit" part of the website.

Comment: I could see `Jährliches Limit`, however I don't understand where is `uncle` element.

Comment: the 10000, 5000, and 2500 euro text

Comment: Use `find_elements` with this xpath `//div[text()='Jährliches Limit']/../following-sibling::div` this should return 3 numbers.